# How to use a Bootstrap number input in rShiny

Tags: r, input, bootstrap-4, shiny

I'd like to replicate the look of this bootstrap numeric [input](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/forms/inputs/) in Shiny:

[image]

So far in shiny, I've only been able to use the standard, pre-packaged numericInput().
Does anybody know how do this?

Thanks!